# How to perform partial deserialization of std::map by C++ boost::serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a highly formatted file with large amount of data which I used pretty frequently so I store it into std::map and serialize it with boost::serialization library. the serialization code looks like this:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream ofs {};
ofs.push (boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor ());
ofs.push (boost::iostreams::file_sink (file_name));
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa {ofs};
oa << my_map;
```

But every time I might just need part of the map, like a certain key-value pair. So I am wondering whether I can partially de-serialize the map from the file and only retrieving the pair I specify? In this way I don't have to read the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an index of your data, though that's a bit harder to use in the presence of compression. If your data file was uncompressed, and say each record was on one line, then you could make an index in which you store consecutive *offsets* of each line in fixed-width records, say unsigned 64-bit numbers.

To locate line 5112, you'd open the index, seek to `5112 * 8`, and read two `uint64_t`s, say `a` and `b`. Then you open your data file, seek to `a` and read `b - a` bytes, which is your record.

If the data is compressed, you'll have to look at your compression library and see if it allows you to partially decompress only that region of the file which contains the bytes `[a, b)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply Kerrek. Very helpful! 
Unfortunately it is impractical to store my data in a fixed-width pattern. I guess I will have to store the size of each data in the header of gzip. Then I must define my own compressor for filtering_stream... which is beyond my capabilities. And the "compression" method you mentioned also requires me to do so :-( 
Please correct me if I was wrong! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @bowhan: Just to be clear, your *data* wouldn't be fixed-width, only your *index*. You'll have to build the index once, which is slow, but after than you have essentially random access to your records.

Comment: @Kerrer: I see what you mean! sorry for my misunderstanding. But I still don't know how to do this index Since the keys of map has orders. For example, I wanna retrieve the value of key1, but I don't know where the index of key1 lies in the index file unless I create an index of index. So I think a text index file would be more direct. Actually, by doing random access I feel like losing the sense of map serialization. I could have create a random access file for the original data and read the piece I want every time without building the map? please correct me if I made any mistake! Thanks!